# Correct verb form in two sentences

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

I can't explain why the following sentences are wrong, although I can correct them.

1. > (a) INCORRECT — The table shows the average amount of time advertisements on the Internet
   >   **lasting**.
   >
   > (b) CORRECT — The table shows the average amount of time advertisements on the Internet **last**.
2. > (a) INCORRECT — The graph shows what proportion of UK adolescents **following** a vegetarian diet.
   >
   > (b) CORRECT — The graph shows what proportion of UK  adolescents **follow** a vegetarian diet.
   >
   > (c) CORRECT — The graph shows **the** proportion of UK adolescents **following** a vegetarian diet.

What's the actual grammar going on here?

Comment: Are these real sentences you have seen somewhere?

Comment: Looks to me like cutting and pasting/rewriting without correcting all the sentence. In which case there's no actual grammar, just errors and sloppy editing.

Comment: the actual grammar is just a subject and a verb.  Advertisements last.  pretty simple.

Comment: Those are some good questions that you've asked. :)

Comment: You could also have _The table shows the average amount of time advertisements on the Internet **are lasting**._ and _The graph shows what proportion of UK adolescents **are following** a vegetarian diet._

Answer (score 1):

Verbs have many properties, *tense* (e.g., present, past), *number* (viz., singular and plural), *mood* (e.g., imperative, conditional), but here the inconsistency is in in verb's [grammatical *aspect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect).

There are four grammatical aspects:

- Simple 
  "I ate", "I eat", "I will eat" 
  "I lasted", "I last", "I will last"
- Progressive (ongoing) 
  "I was eating", "I am eating", "I will be eating" 
  "I was lasting", "I am lasting", "I will be lasting"
- Perfect (completed) 
  "I had eaten", "I have eaten", "I will have eaten" 
  "I had lasted", "I have lasted", "I will have lasted"
- Perfect Progressive (completed, but was ongoing) 
  "I had been eating", "I have been eating", "I will have been eating" 
  "I had been lasting", "I have been lasting", "I will have been lasting"

  1. > (a) INCORRECT 
     >   — The table shows the average amount of time advertisements on the Internet **lasting**.
     >     the average amount of time = not progressive 
     >     lasting = progressive.
     >   
     >   (b) CORRECT 
     >   — The table shows the average amount of time advertisements on the Internet **last**. 
     >     the average amount of time = not progressive 
     >     last = not progressive.
  2. > (a) INCORRECT 
     >   — The graph shows what proportion of UK adolescents **following** a vegetarian diet.
     >     what proportion of UK adolescents = not progressive
     >     following = progressive.
     >   
     >   (b) CORRECT 
     >   — The graph shows what proportion of UK adolescents **follow** a vegetarian diet.
     >     what proportion of UK adolescents = not progressive
     >     follow = not progressive.
     >   
     >   (c) CORRECT 
     >   — The graph shows the proportion of UK adolescents following a vegetarian diet. 
     >   In this sentence there is an **implied *that are***:
     >   The graph shows the proportion of UK adolescents **that are** following a vegetarian diet.
     >     the proportion of UK adolescents [that are] = progressive 
     >     following = progressive.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start out by parsing your good sentences, #1.b, #2.b, #2.c, by using brackets to identity the internal complement(s) for the verb "***shows***":

- 1.b) The table shows [the average amount of time(i) *(that) advertisements on the Internet* ***last*** *_*_(i) ].
- 2.b) The graph shows [what proportion of UK  adolescents ***follow*** a vegetarian diet].
- 2.c) The graph shows [***the*** proportion of UK adolescents ***following*** a vegetarian diet].

You can see from the above that there seems to be three different types of constructions involved, w.r.t. ***show***'s internal complement(s). Each one would probably involve a good hunk of time and text to explain. I'm not sure if you're really interested in such a detailed grammatical explanation. If you actually are, then you might want to pose a new question where you asked about exactly one of those example sentences (perhaps it could be paired with one of the ungrammatical examples).

Also, you might notice something if you parse the ungrammatical examples and then compare them to the good ones. But, unfortunately, that might need to have the good ones grammatically explained first.

Anyway, let me give some quick impressions w.r.t. your first example set.

- 1.b) The table shows [the average amount of time(i) *(that) advertisements on the Internet* ***last*** *_*_(i) ].

The expression that is in italics "*(that) advertisements on the Internet last* _*_*(i)" seems to be a relative clause, which modifies the nominal within the noun phrase "*the average amount of time*". The relativized gap ("_(i)") is linked to that same nominal. A possible interpretation for that relative clause could be something like: *advertisements on the Internet last [an average of five hours].*

You can try to use that explanation as you attempt to parse the ungrammatical version #1. Maybe that explanation will be helpful, maybe it won't. (Note that, *in general*, relative clauses are finite clauses. But the complement in version #1 seems to involve a non-finite clause as a modifier.)

And then, you can attempt to create explanations for your other good versions, #2.b and #2.c.

Hope some of this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

In the first sentence, the meaning that I gather is that the average amount of time advertisements *last*. So you can see that the matter is to put forward a general fact and hence that would require the sentence to be in simple present tense. Hence *last* and not *lasting*.

In the second sentence, the subject is *what the graph shows* and there is no helping verb present in the sentence (in this case **is**) which compels you to correct the verb *following* to *follow* since simple grammar does not allow us to use *ing*-words in the absence of a helping verb.